# Memory usage in infinite loop

Tags: c#

I'm curious how much memory an infinite loop uses on my computer. I know it depends what the Thread is doing, but let's say it's reading some Json and parsing the string with a regex. Does this store junk in the memory with every loop?

```
public  void loadCookie()
{
    Thread myT = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            getUserID();
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }  
    });

    myT.IsBackground = true;
    myT.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disregarding any other problem and just focusing on your memory.

The answer is every `allocation` (strangely enough) allocates memory. You can assume if you call just about any method there will be allocations, how many depends on the method. However, *.net* is built with a *garbage collector* that will monitor this issue and (when it feels the need) will clean up and or compact your out of scope *allocations*.

*Garbage collection* isn't free, meaning, it pauses all your *threads* to do its job, so in certain situations this might not be ideal. however in the majority of the time it's not a big deal.

If you are worried about *allocations*, or want to keep pressure off the *GC*, then you need to monitor your *memory*, I suggest one of many *memory profilers* to work out what's been *allocated* and do some research on the *garbage collector* and how it works.

Comment: Thanks. I will look more into it.

Answer (score 1):

Insert this line inside the loop to find out!

```
Console.WriteLine($"Mem usage: {GC.GetTotalMemory(true):#,0} bytes");
```

Comment: Thank you! This will help me.